# Why is strpos working the first time, but not the second?

Tags: php, strpos

I´m using strpos two timer. In the first if/else it works well but in the second it doesn´t work. This is my code:

```
if (strpos($word, "mono") == true) {
    $type = "Monobloc";
} else {
    $type = "Articulated";
}

if ($word, "galva") == true) {
    $coating = "Galvanized Rod";
} elseif (strpos($word, "epoxi") == true) {
    $coating = "EPOXI 100%";
} elseif ($word, "electro") == true) {
    $coating = "Electrozinced";
}
```

Example:
If the variable word has the value "galva-mono" $type should be "Monobloc" and $coating should be "Galvanized Rod". The problem is that it is assigning well the $type but in the coating it doen´t enter in the if clause.

Comment: This line should trigger a syntax error: `if ($word, "galva") == true) {` error reporting/reading logs would help here.

Comment: Could you give examples of $word, does it always contain a type and a coating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/strpos):

> Warning
>
> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

You are checking the result with `== true` instead of `!== false`.

So, try this code:

```
if (strpos($word, "mono") !== false) {
    $type = "Monobloc";
} else {
    $type = "Articulated";
}

if (strpos($word, "galva") !== false) {
    $coating = "Galvanized Rod";
} elseif (strpos($word, "epoxi") !== false) {
    $coating = "EPOXI 100%";
} elseif (strpos($word, "electro") !== false) {
    $coating = "Electrozinced";
}
```